# Добавление в таблицу MySQL в Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Как сделать так, чтобы сообщения записывались в одну строку БД допустим через запятую. Код выполняется в цикле и сообщения каждый раз записываются в разные строки

```
 private void insertMessage(String message){
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection_BD.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ueres (message_user) VALUES (?)")){
            preparedStatement.setString(1, message);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не надо записывать данные в строку через запятую. С такими данными в БД потом невозможно будет нормально работать. следует сделать отдельную таблицу, в которой будет id пользователя и отдельное его сообщение на строку. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: Ну тогда с переносом строки, в качестве обучения интересно ка это сделать

Comment: какая разница какой разделитель, если у вас в поле таблицы users будут все его сообщения и вы какое нибудь из них захотите удалить, что вы будете делать ? читать все сообщения в программу, разыскивать среди текста нужную строку, как то вырезать ее и оставшееся писать обратно в БД ? Реляционные БД в принципе не предназначены для работы с данными в таком виде. Но если очень хочется, то конечно можно, но для этого надо делать insert если записи еще нет и update (т.е. изменение существующей записи) если она уже есть

Comment: если использовать команды insert и update, то каждое следующее сообщение перезаписывает предыдущее, а мне этого не надо

Comment: правильно, записывает новую версию данных. но вы же можете прочитать старые данные, добавить к ним новые и записать обновленную версию. или преобразовать данные прямо на стороне SQL, например с помощью функции MySQL concat()

Comment: А вообще продолжая хотеть сделать именно так вы наживаете себе огромное кол-во проблем в будующем, вроде случаного повреждения данных, их потерю, сотни строк кода только для обеспечения работы этих механизмов, с кучей костылей. Если же данные будут нормализованы, то все будет происходить само собой, простейшими операциями, без риска потери данных